# How can search for text that can vary, in a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a form that I have people fill out that links to a Spreadsheet.

One of the questions is multiple choice/selection and stores all of the answers someone gives in one cell delineated by a comma. Example "Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3".

I can search for and separate all of the answers pretty easily using

```
=if(ISNUMBER(search("Phone Call",'Form Responses 1'!G2)) = True,"Yes","No")
```

The very last option on this question though is an "Other" option where the person can write in their own answer which could be anything. I need to be able to search out or isolate just that other answer and display it in another cell. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can extract all the default options with `REGEXEXTRACT` and format the rest of the answers.*

#### Formula:

Assuming that your default options are `Phone Call`, `Text Message` and `Email`, you can do the following:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE('Form Responses 1'!B2,"Phone Call,|Text Message,|Email,|", ""))
```

**Rundown:**

- Use `REGEXREPLACE` to remove all instances of the strings `Phone Call,`, `Text Message,` and `Email,` from the string contained in `'Form Responses 1'!B2`
- Use `TRIM` to remove the preceding and trailing spaces of the string that's left.

**What you need to do:**

- Change the options inside the regular expression to match your available multiple choice answers.

#### Visual Example:

For the following input on the question:

[image: Question on Form]

The Sheet will record the data as such:

[image: Form Responses in Sheet]

And the formula will extract the relevant information from the "Other" category:

[image: Using the Formula]

#### References:

- [REGEXEXTRACT - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- [TRIM function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en)